# Need Help, looping to database takes too long

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, foxpro

i would like to ask for help as to what makes this code take too long to process :

```
using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()){
      while (dr.Read())
      {
          count += 1;
     if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AMOUNT"]) ==     Convert.ToDecimal(0.00) &&
     Convert.ToDecimal(dr["PENALTY"]) == Convert.ToDecimal(0.00) && Convert.ToDecimal(dr["DEPDIV"]) == Convert.ToDecimal(0.00))
      {
          //Cancel Upload and let user check is .DTLS contains Amount
          ViewBag.Message = "UPLOADING CANCELLED!! : .DTLS file does not contain any amount for the Following Fields :"
       + "AMOUNT UNPAID, "
       + "PENALTY "
       + "DEPDIV "
       + "PLEASE CHECK INGRES SETTING FOR MONEY FORMAT(REQUIRED MONEY FORMAT IS : II_MONEY_FORMAT=L:á"
       + "THEN REDOWNLOAD THE .MAST and DTLS FILE from the DELINQUENT EMPLOYERS EXTRACTION UTILITY BEFORE UPLOADING";

          return View();
      }
      else
      {
          string Acctno, EyerID, Percov;
          decimal Amount, Penalty, DepDiv;

          EyerID = dr["EYERID"].ToString().Trim();
          Percov = dr["PERCOV"].ToString().Trim();
          Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["AMOUNT"]);
          Penalty = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["PENALTY"]);
          DepDiv = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["DEPDIV"]);
          Acctno = SaveUpdateTransMaster.spRetrieveAcctNo(EyerID, brid, "MCDEL", Convert.ToDateTime(currCutoff));

          ListLedger.Add(new TransLedger
          {
              EyerID = EyerID,
              AcctNo = Acctno,
              Percov = Percov,
              AmtDue = Amount,
              Penalty = Penalty,
              DepDiv = DepDiv,
          });
      }
  }
}

"MCDEL");
}

foreach (var row in ListLedger)
{
   SaveUpdateTransMaster.spUploadTransLedgerCA(row.AcctNo, row.EyerID, 
   currCutoff, row.Percov,Convert.ToDecimal(row.AmtDue), Convert.ToDecimal(row.Penalty), 
   Convert.ToDecimal(row.DepDiv), brid, "MCDEL");
}
```

Here is my scenario :

i usually fetch millions of rows to a FoxPRO DBF, store it to a List
and loop it insert it to the DB through StoredProc.

Comment: which part of your code takes the most amount of time? Given the example you provided, one could only guess that both the `using` and  `foreach` statements could be bottlenacks, because one accesses a Database and the otehrone seems to do some network action, right?

Comment: looping million times is not a good idea, try to find a way to import data from DBF using import/export wizard. there also might be some free tools for this purpose.

Comment: @nozzleman - sir, the part where it usually takes time is the the whole while loop process. for 1 hour it only added 72936 rows to the list

Comment: consider what @FLICKER or try to find a way to impove the executed query. But take note the querying mollions of rows simply might take time. maybe it is better to constrain the queried amount of data.

Comment: Does FoxPro DBF allow OpenXML. If so, you can convert your data into XML and Insert it in the database

Comment: one more option is loop on million rows and generate a tab separated file containing all data and then use BCP to import all data in one shot.

Comment: @FLICKER  i dont think i can use an import / export wizard here, cause i need to attach the generated Account no to the raw data from the foxpro here, but hey, thanks for the advices :D

Comment: @FLICKER BCP can make up for the insertion side, but the looping is still needed though, if i can optimize that part, inserting is easy. :D

Comment: can you use BCP? it is a command line tool. Note that inserting millions of rows one by one is time consuming. if you want to do everything by coding in your program, I don't think you can get a acceptable performance.

Comment: @mj5460, It seems you are storing all rows in ListLedger. I think that is not efficient. also the last loop when you call spUploadTransLedgerCA, will call stored procedure millions of time? I believe you need to change your approach. you might be able read the DBF as binary and avoid using DataReader.

Comment: @FLICKER there's SQLBulkcopy for coding side.

Comment: Also, since no one has mentioned it already: What is the bandwidth between the pc your application runs on and the database servers? Is in on LAN or over an intranet (different locations) or the internet? Low bandwidth will make the data transfer slower.

Comment: @scheien i run this locally, i also think its my pc. it's a little bit outdated, dual core.

Comment: What is the Command text, in other words what is the SQL that you're hitting the FoxPro data with? If it is not an Rushmore-optimised query in light of the indexes available on the FoxPro side, it will be sub-optimal.

Comment: @AlanB it's just a simple select.

Comment: Doesn't matter - it still needs to be optimised in FoxPro terms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're duplicating some of your code. When you create each row, you are converting Amount, Penalty and and DepDiv to decimals, and then again when you are uploading them, you are converting those fields to decimal again. In addition, you are computing them in the conditional portion of the if statement. You should probably compute the values for each row before the if statement to reduce some of the code duplication and save time. Even if you save just a millisecond per row, that's almost 17 minutes per million rows.

However, as Alan B suggested, perhaps you could post the code of the Foxpro query and we can look at that for improvements in speed and/or data format. It's possible the query could also be altered to output something you could directly import to SQL Server, such as a comma or tab delimited file.